# What is the difference between "detrimental" and "harmful"?

Tags: word-choice

Is there any difference regarding the usage of *detrimental* and *harmful*?
I am not a native English speaker, so I don't understand the different nuance of these words.

Answer (score 2):

*Harmful* means (basing on what the NOAD reports) "causing or likely to cause harm"; *detrimental* means "tending to cause harm".

*Harmful* should be used for something that effectively (or probably) causes harm, while *detrimental* should be used for something that frequently (or regularly) causes harm.

Answer (score 1):

The two words have very close meaning. I would say that “detrimental” sounds slightly more conditional than “harmful”, but it might only be because it is a less common word.

Comment: Is there any dictionary or thesaurus describes or defines subtle differences between synonyms?

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that *harmful* can cover a far wider range of harm, whereas *detrimental* has connotations of a minor effect that decreases the efficiency of whatever it's been applied to without stopping it from working entirely.